# FCN in TensorFlow missing crop layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, caffe

I am currently trying to implement [FCN for semantic segmentation](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf) in TensorFlow as it was previously done in Caffe [here](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org).

Unfortunately I'm struggling with following 3 things:

1) How to map "Deconvolution" layer from Caffe to TensorFlow? Is it correctly `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose`?

2) How to map "Crop" layer from Caffe to TensorFlow? Unfortunately I can't see any alternative in TensorFlow. Is there equivalent for this in TensorFlow?

3) Does Caffe `SoftmaxWithLoss` correspond to TensorFlow softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits?

Thank you in advance for any advices, hints and help.

**EDIT 9th May 2016:**

1) I have found out that `tf.nn.conv2_transpose` really corresponds to deconvolution layer.

2) Crop layer for now seems to be really a problem. I have found out that there actually exists [`tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/image.html#resize_image_with_crop_or_pad), but this seems to be impossible to use for this purposes, because it can't work with dynamically created tensors nor with 4D tensors that you need to use after `tf.nn.conv2_transpose` layer.

Some more information might be on: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2049

**EDIT 17th May 2016:**

I have followed @24hours advice and build FCN in tensorflow, though I was not able to make it train on data of the arbitrary size.

2) Crop layer is really not needed.

3) I have used `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` at the end and it worked for me.

Comment: 2.) crop layer in Caffe seems to crop input tensor into same size with 2nd input tensor. I assume this is to make sure elewise sum will work. I ignore this layer in my tensorflow implementation.
3.) Reshape prediction into [batch_size, h x w x class_num] then proceed to calculate loss value. I suggest `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`

Comment: @24hours 2.) I think that this won't work, because if you'll compute deconvolution output shape (in a same way as it is implemented in caffe), then you'll get output from the deconvolution layer > than number of labels. The workaround you might have done is setting the output of the `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` to the same shape as the input image? Have you done that in your implementation?

Comment: Indeed, I set the `output_shape` to the same size with input from pooling layer. I should perhaps mention that I resized the input image into `224 x 224`. This doens't seems to be the case in Caffe implementation. It seems to operation on variable image size. I can't understand what does `pad size = 100` mean in caffe implementation. Author state that it is to center the percept region. Since tensorflow conv do not support it, i will have to work with no padding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the advice from @24hours I have found answer to all the 3 questions. Unfortunately FCN of arbitrary size in tensorflow is a bit more complicated than in caffe, but hopefully I'll solve that soon as well.

1) `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` can be used.

2) Crop layer is not needed, `output_size` of the `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` layer can be used instead.

3) At the end I have used `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`

Comment: TensorFlow slim has an fcn implementation of [resnet_v2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/resnet_v2.py) available now.

Comment: Do you have your code somewhere public? I'm currently looking for a simple example on how to implement the upsampling/deconvolution part  for an arbitrary CNN architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way for solving arbitrary size image in tensorflow, by implementing crop layer. Now it can be used any size of image you want, when just single image is passed. More about my solution is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45632285/3134418