# Fully Convolution Net (FCN) on Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to reimplement FCN on tensorflow. I have implemented the deconvolution layer as such.

```
up8_filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([64, 64, 21, 21]))
prob_32 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(score, up8_filter, output_shape = [batch_size, 224, 224, 21], strides = [1, 32, 32, 1])
tf.histogram_summary('fc8_filter', up8_filter)
```

Training looks fine with the loss value dropping until it become `Nan`. I checked tensorboard and it suggest that `up8_filter` seems to diverged.

[image]

Is there a way to regularize the weight value in Tensorflow ?
I have tried following methods

1. Lower learning rate
2. Zero-mean image

I did not pad image to 100 pixel as per FCN implementation since Tensorflow `conv2d` does not support it. I converted VGG weight using [caffe-tensorflow](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow), there is not much I can do to alter it's network structure.

I'm sorry for the confusing question, there is so many thing to go wrong and I'm not sure where to start.

Snippet for the loss value.

> Step 1: loss = 732171599872.00
>   Step 10: loss = 391914520576.00
>   Step 20: loss = 32141299712.00
>   Step 30: loss = 1255705344.00

[Update]:

Loss Function 
loss32

```
 loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                                    tf.reshape(prob_32, [batch_size*224*224, 21]),
                                    tf.reshape(lbl_ph, [-1]) ))
```

[Update2]

I followed suggest by ziky90 and it worked. The training now converged and deconv filter seems to stop diverge. I will report agian for the accuracy.

Comment: lower learning rate more?

Comment: what is your loss function?

Comment: I am playing with FCNs right now as well, trying to make them work in tensorflow. 
If I compare this with the reference caffe implementation, then I see, that you are not initialising weights by bilinear interpolation in the `deconvolution`/`tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` layer, but by tf.truncated_normal.
Btw. I am solving related stuff at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746860/fcn-in-tensorflow-missing-crop-layer

Comment: I did not see code specific in FCN paper / implementation which initialize deconv filter weight.

Comment: Hopefully we're both speaking about the paper from Jonathan Long? If yes, then if you have a look on the reference implementation in caffe, they initialise it here: https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/surgery.py#L35 and this is called from https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn32s/solve.py#L20

Comment: I have just created official answer to make it easier to find for next people that would have similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I compare this with the reference caffe implementation, then I see, that you are not initialising weights by bilinear interpolation in the `deconvolution`/`tf.nn.conv2d_transpose` layer, but by `tf.truncated_normal`.

You can have look on the reference implementation in caffe [here](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/surgery.py#L35) and it is called from [here](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn32s/solve.py#L20)

Answer (score 5):

Also have a look at my Tensorflow [FCN implementation](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/tensorflow-fcn). Training works when using this [loss function](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/tensorflow-fcn/blob/86645753421a6b045182b69d6c68b6720670a3b8/loss.py) in combination with [this](https://github.com/TensorVision/TensorVision/blob/9db59e2f23755a17ddbae558f21ae371a07f1a83/tensorvision/train.py) training script.

Here are some insights I gained when I implemented FCN.

1. The deconv filter need to be initialized bilinear.
2. `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` can be used but it causes numerical instabilities in some cases. See also this [Tensorflow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2327). I therefore decided to implement cross entropy using tensor operations.
3. When using large images (which results in large `softmax batches`) reducing the training rate is useful. Adam optimizer in combination with a learning rate of `1e-6` seems to be useful.

Comment: Hi MarvMind, for your FCN implementation, you also provided test code like test_fcn16_vgg.py. Does that overlap with the evaluation script included in tensorvision? Can you elaborate the workflow of using tensorvison combined with FCN implementation?