# Dynamic Tensor Aligment/Cropping

Tags: tensorflow

I implemented Fully-Convolution Network at TensorFlow. It use encdoder-decoder structure. 
When training, I use always same image size (`224x224`, using random crop) and everything works nicely.

In interference phase, I want to predict one image at a time, because I want to use full-image (not croped). For example, such image have size `[406,256]`. And here is problem.
In Encoder-Decoder architecture I add two tesors [(z = x + y)](https://gist.github.com/melgor/0e43cadf742fe3336148ab64dd63138f#file-linknet_tf-py-L166). When training, sizes of both tensor matches. When predicting my single image, sizes does not match (tensor sizes: `[1,47,47,64]` vs `[1,46,46,64]`). I think it is cause by some rounding done in Conv and Pool layer.

What should I change in my architecture to works for any image size I want? Should I change rounding parameters? Or add 'cropping' of tensor?

Link to implementation of architecture:
https://gist.github.com/melgor/0e43cadf742fe3336148ab64dd63138f
(the problem occur in line 166)

Comment: just resize your inputs to `[224, 224]`

Comment: I do not want resizing the input because then I will then loose some `spatial information`. My model was learned with right `aspect-ratio` (no image resizing). At interference I would also want to have right `aspect-ratio`.

Also I could just split the images to several rectangular region and then merge it. But I want this model to works reasonable fast and work at Mobile with different input resolution.

Comment: Have you looked into why at prediction time the tensor sizes do not match ?

Comment: It was rounding errors as 406 is not divided by 8. But crop-and-align function resolve this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution for variable input size:)

What we really need was a 'Crop-layer', that crop one tensor to match other. I found really similar layer here: http://tf-unet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/tf_unet/layers.html
(crop_and_concat).

I have just made it `crop_and_add' and it is working:

```
def crop_and_add(x1,x2):
    x1_shape = tf.shape(x1)
    x2_shape = tf.shape(x2)
    # offsets for the top left corner of the crop
    offsets = [0, (x1_shape[1] - x2_shape[1]) // 2, (x1_shape[2] - x2_shape[2]) // 2, 0]
    size = [-1, x2_shape[1], x2_shape[2], -1]
    x1_crop = tf.slice(x1, offsets, size)
    return x1_crop + x2
```

All addition in model I replaced by above layer (so merging encoder and decoder data).

Also, the input to model need to be defined as:

```
image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, None, None, 3], name="input_image")
```

So we know that we will pass single image and that image have 3 channels. but we do not know neither width nor height. And it works very nice! (40 FPS on K80 as AWS P2, size of image is 224x{}-shoter side of image have 224)

FYI, I was also trying to run [ENET](https://github.com/kwotsin/TensorFlow-ENet/blob/master/enet.py) (2x faster than LinkNet), but in TensorFlow it is slower. I think it is because of PReLu (which is slow at TF). Also it does not support arbitraty size of image becauese of UnPool layer, which need to have predefined output size by list of integers (not placeholders). So LinkNet look better in case of Speed and Performacance in TF.